# Разметка для размера hdpi в ландшафтной ориентации

Tags: android

Всем привет! Кто знает как создать разметку для ландшафтной ориентации на hdpi экране??? Я пробовал создать папку "layout-land-hdpi", "layout-land-large", но что-то не получается.

Comment: решил я проблему, оказывается надо было писать "layout-normal-land" для hdpi устройства.

Answer (score 1):

layout-large-port , layout-large-land - должно помочь
а hdpi тут не причём. hdpi это плотность а не размер.
[link text](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, мне уже тоже сказали что между hdpi и layout-large и т.д нет никакой зависимости.